# C# LDAP AD Authentication - Separate Network

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I am working on a solution to use Active Directory to authenticate our applications, we are using LDAP protocol, we have several domain controllers that all sync together.

I have built out an application that works with Active Directory authentication using our internal domain controller which is on the same network I run the application, as soon as I point to the Domain Controller hosted on Amazon (separate network) I get an error response saying the server can not be contacted. When I open command prompt and ping the server using its domain name I can get a reply.

The AWS AD server is new and was spun up just a few weeks ago for this project, I can't tell if this is an issue with the AD setup on that machine or if I have to modify my code to access AD on a separate network. Here is the function I use to authenticate against AD - again this works on the domain controller hosted on the same network I'm executing but as soon as I update the config to use the AWS DC it fails. Sys admins are looking into the server to make sure everything is OK, but I'm expecting that they will say everything is configured correctly.

```
public bool IsAuthenticated(string username, string pwd)
{
    var domainAndUsername = _domain + @"\" + username;
    var entry = new DirectoryEntry(_ldapPath, domainAndUsername, pwd);
    _username = username;

try
{
    //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
    var unused = entry.NativeObject;

    var search = new DirectorySearcher(entry) {Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")"};
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

    var result = search.FindOne();
    if (result == null) return false;

    //Update the new path to the user in the directory.
    _ldapPath = result.Path;
    _filterAttribute = (string) result.Properties["cn"][0];
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Exception Handling
    // throw 
}

return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I open command prompt and ping the server using its domain name I
>   can get a reply.

Ping is not a good test. Just because ping works, doesn't mean that anything else will or will not work.

A better test is using the `telnet` client. It's a quick test that opens a TCP connection on whatever port you specify. That will tell you if there are any firewalls in the way preventing the connection.

It uses port 389 by default, so try that. From the command prompt:

```
telnet domain.com 389
```

A blank screen means the connection succeeded. If it fails, it will say so.

Here are the ports that Active Directory uses. You can specify a different port if you want to.

- 389: LDAP - single domain only (the default if you don't specify anything)
- 3268: Global Catalog - your whole forest
- 636: LDAP over SSL
- 3269: Global Catalog over SSL

Comment: Resulted in a "Could not open a connection to the host" response. Forwarded information to networking team - thanks for your help!